# Como inserir dinamicamente um DNS no /etc/hosts através de um script bash?

Tags: bash, dns, host

Tenho um script bash `runmydocker.sh` cujo objetivo é recuperar a string enviada pelo usuário no momento que ele estiver chamando esse script e criar um DNS no `etc/hosts`.
Exemplo:

O usuário (desenvolvedor) vai chamar `runmydocker.sh mysitephp7.com`. Esse script vai recuperar a string `mysitephp7.com` e vai inseri-la no `/etc/hosts` como `127.0.0.1 mysitephp7.com` e então inicializar o docker.
Em seguida quando o desenvolvedor escrever na url do browser `mysitephp7.com` o sistema seria carregado usando o servidor docker. Note que esse DNS não existia no hosts antes do script.

Todos os passos estão pronto com exceção da inserção dessa string `mysitephp7.com`.com no /etc/hosts.

qual seria a maneira adequada para conseguir fazer isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dentro do seu script *runmydocker.sh* teremos basicamente o seguinte:

```
#!/bin/bash

HOST=$1
# Atribui o primeiro parâmetro passado no script a variável HOST

echo "127.0.0.1 $HOST" >> /etc/hosts
# Adiciona a saida "127.0.0.1 $HOST" ao final do arquivo /etc/hosts
```

O redirecionador **>>** insere a saída do seu comando ao final do arquivo.
Mais sobre redirecionadores [clique aqui](https://www.vivaolinux.com.br/dica/Redirecionamento-no-Shell).